# How to prevent logo from resizing in fixed header as the page is scrolled down?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The theme I'm working with shrinks the menu and logo while it remains fixed when you scroll down the page.  I can't figure out how to stop it from making the logo smaller, I want it to stay the same size.

I think this is the relevant code:

```
<a class="logo" style="">
<img class="sd-res logo-normal" width="208" height="82" alt="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/logo-new1.png" style="max-height: 49.7px;">
```

http://bit.ly/1ZzgElV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line of css code:

```
.header.stuck .logo img {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Every time you scroll the window, the `max-height` of the image is overwriten so you need add the `!important` prefix.

Comment: Thanks! That did it.